# SQL Server error after compiling python program (does not exists or access denied)

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, pyodbc

I am trying to compile a python program that uses pyodbc.
I have the following python script :

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server-name;UID=user;PWD=password;DATABASE=database-name;')
print "no errors"
```

When I launch the script with python I get `no errors` as expected.
But when I compile the script (I tried with py2exe, cx-freeze, pyinstaller and nuitka) and launch it I get the following error :

```
SQL Server does not exists or access denied
```

The server is not a problem because the not-compiled script worked fine.
I believe that some files are not included during the compilation but I don't know where to start searching.
The py2exe script is :

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(options = {
        'py2exe': {
            'includes': 'decimal',
            },
        },
         console=['main.py'])
```

And I launch it using `python setup.py py2exe`

Also I am using python 2.7

How can I fix this error, where should I start looking ?

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE :
After trying with nuitka and pyinstaller and getting the same error, it seems that the problem occurs either at compile time either when I run the compiled app.

Are there some dlls that I could re-download to make it work or some logs to look at the problem ?

note : I already re-installed my python distribution.

UPDATE 2 :

I have an Anaconda installation (32bits python 2.7) I reinstalled the last version two days ago from [here](https://www.anaconda.com/download/).

I am running the .exe from a command prompt with the current working directory pointing to the folder where the executable is located.

I run it with the same command prompt that I used to compile it (that means with the same user I guess).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have had success using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) with pyodbc applications accessing SQL Server. If PyInstaller also doesn't work for you (in addition to py2exe and cx_Freeze) then it's probably an issue with *how* you are running the compiled app instead of an issue with the app itself.

Comment: How are you launching the compiled program? Are you running it from a command prompt with the current working directory pointing to the folder where the executable file is located? Are you running the compiled app as the same user that can run the un-compiled version? Also, are you doing this on a Windows box with a standard install of CPython (from python.org)?

Comment: Yes to all I think, I updated my question.

Comment: I found a partial solution when trying different directories, I was compiling from a mapped drive, when I move the file at the root of C: it runs normaly. Any Idea why ?

Comment: Executable "stuff" (EXEs, DLLs, etc.) on a network drive may be considered untrusted and blocked by some OS policy on your machine. That should not be an issue for deployment, however, since your installer will almost certainly copy the the required file(s) to a local folder. (Although running from the root of C: can also be problematic for applications, but apparently not in this case.)